# Working with lists of data from server

Tags: android, sqlite

I am going to populate data from server to a listview (endless). What is the best practice for doing this? Should I cache this data to local db?

Update: Usually list contains not much data about each item. But those item types (say it a "company info") I am also going to use for favorites which should always be stored locally. So I would like to reuse the same table for favorites and items temporally downloaded from server.

Comment: What is the nature of the data? How large?

Comment: are the data change frequently on server??

Comment: Data is not changing frequently actually. But universal solution for frequently changeable data is preferable.

Comment: If data not changed frequently then populate data from server and store it to local db.. Now make a webservice which return yes or no on data changed on server side. So make this call on everytime when your application launched. If data changed on server side then populate again data from server and update your local database. It gives best user experience on performance..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly as per per your question please be specific about your requirement .

To handle data from server to listview .. The data that is obtained from server ( i.e parsed json , xml etc) need to sotred in some collection say ArrayList or Hash map etc.

These list can be populated from the above collections.

But if you intend to have permanent storage for the data in the app i.e offline browsing etc  than you should save the data in sqlite db and use Cursor Adpater etc for showing the list.

So,  the way you use the android recommended widgets and views depends upon the your requirement in mind + the optimized way to handle those things in efficient way.